# Printing Report Footer At the End Of Last Page(Detail Section) In Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, footer

I am working in Cystal Report 10. I have a requirement to print the Report Footer To The Remaining of Last Page(Of Details Section). In my case the report footer is being printed on the new page.
  Lots Of Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solved the problem by Adding page Footer Instead Of Report Footer And writing following Suppress Formula  for my Page Footer.

**Suppress Formula**

```
    PageNumber <> TotalPageCount.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand fully but I have solved similar problems by moving the report to a new page footer section and suppressing the new page footer section on all but the last page using `Not onLastRecord` in the section suppression formula.